# Python, move turtle to relative coordinates

Tags: python

I couldn't find anything on the python docs or here.
It is a pretty simple question, how can I move my turtle lets say -15 in x and -15 in y relatively. So I don't want to go to those positions specificly, I want to move it -15 in the x and y directions.
I could only find how to move it to absolute positions, is there a workaround?

Comment: What turtle? Is this in the context of a program you have written, or some library?

Comment: It's the default turtle library in python that you can reach by doing import turtle.

Comment: Assuming the turtle is facing in the positive y direction initially, `turtle.backward(15)`, then `turtle.left(90)`, then `turtle.forward(15)` should do it. Take a look at the docs, these are documented pretty clearly: https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/turtle.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simply get current position, change it and move to it

```
turtle.goto( turtle.pos() + (15,-15) )
```

Comment: When I do `alex.goto(alex.pos() + (-20,-20)`. My turtles name is alex and when I do this it gives me invalid syntax?

Comment: @czaarek99, you are missing the `)` at the end

Answer (score 0):

```
import turtle

shelly = turtle.Turtle()

def relative_move(x=None, y=None):

    if x is not None:
        shelly.setx(shelly.xcor() + x)

    if y is not None:
        shelly.setx(shelly.ycor() + y)

relative_move(x=15)
relative_move(x=-10)

print shelly.xcor() #should be 5
```